# React leaflet: Array.map function not rendering Marker component to Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to add two `<Marker/>` components to my map, I am using the useState hook to keep track of the markers.

When a user clicks the map it adds the current longitude and latitude of that point to an array which represents the markers.

Logging the markers array shows the two objects which do indeed contain their respective lat, lng.

```
[LatLng, LatLng]
0: LatLng {lat: 40.80694139700055, lng: -73.94622242203457}
1: LatLng {lat: 40.668585096493445, lng: -73.48779014853261}
length: 2
```

This is my Map component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import LocateControl from '../LocateControl/LocateControl.jsx';
import MapboxLayer from '../MapboxLayer/MapboxLayer.jsx';
import L from "leaflet";
import LCG from 'leaflet-control-geocoder';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

export default function MyMap({getAddressFromLatLong}) {
  var [latLng, setlatlng] = useState(null);
  var [zoom, setZoom] = useState(4);
  var [map, setData] = useState([]);
  var [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);
  var [markers, setMarkers] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("markers ", markers);
    if (latLng != null){
    var geocoder = new L.Control.geocoder();
    var latLngParser = new L.Control.Geocoder.latLng();

     geocoder.options.geocoder.reverse(latLng, 5, (address)=>{
        getAddressFromLatLong(address[0].name)
       }, null)
  }
  }, [latLng, markers]);


var customMarker = new L.icon({
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
});

function updateLatLng(e) {
  setlatlng(e.latlng);
}

function addMarker(e){
  if (markers.length < 2){
    setlatlng(e.latlng);
    setMarkers(markers => markers.concat(e.latlng))
  }
}

function toggleAnimate() {
  setAnimate(animate => !animate);
}

  var MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN;

  var locateOptions = {
    position: 'topright',
    strings: {
      title: 'Show me where I am, yo!'
    },
    onActivate: () => {} // callback before engine starts retrieving locations
  };

  return map ? (
    <>
      <label>
        <input
          className="animate-panning"
          checked={animate}
          onChange={toggleAnimate}
          type="checkbox"
        />
        Animate panning
      </label>

      <Map animate={animate} zoom={zoom} onClick={addMarker}>
         {latLng && markers.map((position, idx)=> {
          {console.log("position ", position)}
          {console.log("idx ", idx);}
          <Marker key={`marker-${idx}`} onDrag={updateLatLng} draggable={true} position={position} icon={customMarker}>
          <Popup>
            This is your starting point!
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
         })}
        <MapboxLayer
          accessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
          style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        />
        <LocateControl options={locateOptions} startDirectly />
      </Map>
    </>
  ) : (
    'Data is Loading...'
  );
}
```

Comment: What is all this? Where's the minimal reproducible example? Have you tried hardcoding markers on to the map instead of mapping a dynamic data structure?

Comment: I agree this would be a lot easier to help you debug if we had a working example of the problem.  Perhaps a codesandbox?